# Remote debugging of Python server with rpdb

Tags: python, django, docker, remote-debugging, pdb

I need to **debug remote server**, Python.

My Python app is running inside Docker container on some server and I have **ssh** access to that server.

For remote debugging I want to use [rpdb](https://coderwall.com/p/ttbtgq/python-remote-debugging-with-pdb) (I don't know other tools for that).

My steps:

1. enter remote server via ssh
2. `pip install rpdb`
3. add to code line `import rpdb; rpdb.Rpdb(port=5555).set_trace()`
4. run `./redeploy.sh` (this command will run my application)
5. `telnet 127.0.0.1 5555`

As a result I get:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-1-0-345:~$ telnet 127.0.0.1 5555
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I open url which is supposed to call `rpdb` and I get nothing. So, how I can reach `rpdb` from command line then?

Comment: @caio maybe you can help?

Comment: you need to connect to your server IP address, not to localhost (127.0.0.1) one. Moreover you need networking between your container and host os to be configured to forward your incoming connection

Comment: please show how you launch your docker container in order to check whether ports are accessible from host os

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add the `addr` param to the `Rpdb()` to accept the connections.

It'll look like this:

```py
import rpdb; rpdb.Rpdb(addr='0.0.0.0', port=5555).set_trace()
```

Don't forget to add `EXPOSE 5555` to your `Dockerfile` and map the ports on the running container.